# Checkbox check one at a time not working

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

My requirement here is to make user only `check` one `checkbox` at a time. I tried with the below code:-

```
 $('input.chkclass').on('change', function () {
        $('input.chkclass').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
```

and **HTML**

```
<table id="trchkOptions" style='display: none' runat="server">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 5%">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span style="display: inline-block; width: 5%;">
                        <input id="chkOption1" class="chkclass" value="testing" runat="server" type="checkbox" name="chkOption1" /></span>
                    Option 1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;To&nbsp;
                    RA 1,&nbsp; RA 2,&nbsp; CC
                </td>
                <td style="width: 5%">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 5%">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span style="display: inline-block; width: 7%;">
                        <input id="chkOption2" class="chkclass" value="testing" runat="server" type="checkbox" name="chkOption2" /></span>Option
                    2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;To
                    Hemant Shah, Vimal Shah, Rushank Shah, CC
                </td>
                <td style="width: 5%">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 5%">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span style="display: inline-block; width: 5%;">
                        <input id="chkOption3" class="chkclass" value="testing" runat="server" type="checkbox" name="chkOption3" /></span>
                    Option 3&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;To,
                    RA 1,&nbsp; RA 2,&nbsp; CC
                </td>
                <td style="width: 5%">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 5%">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSendFeedback" runat="server" Width="30%" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSendFeedback_Click" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

here is a [live preview](https://jsfiddle.net/em103yvw/1/)

But it is not working.

**Note** I don't want to use `radiobutton` here. I want it with `checkbox` only.

Kindly suggest what is wrong

Comment: `Radio` buttons should be used right ?

Comment: @Rayon: No, I don't want `radio` button here.

Comment: That's precisely what radio buttons are created for. It's not about *wanting* to use it or not.

Comment: @Terry: why i am not using it bcoz, once i check radio button, **then i am not able to uncheck it. If I don't want to check**. At that condition what I will do ??

Comment: Then have a "none" option...? Like a typical survey form. You have a scale, say 1–10, and a "no opinion" option too.

Comment: @Terry: can u show a sample of it..!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$('input.chkclass').not(this).attr('checked', false);
```

instead

```
$('input.chkclass').not(this).prop('checked', false);
```

It may work.

---

**Demo:**

```js
$('input.chkclass').on('change', function() {
  $('input.chkclass').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table id="trchkOptions" style='display: block' runat="server">
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 5%">
    </td>
    <td>
      <span style="display: inline-block; width: 5%;">
                        <input id="chkOption1" class="chkclass" value="testing" runat="server" type="checkbox" name="chkOption1" /></span>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 5%">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 5%">
    </td>
    <td>
      <span style="display: inline-block; width: 7%;">
                        <input id="chkOption2" class="chkclass" value="testing" runat="server" type="checkbox" name="chkOption2" /></span>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 5%">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 5%">
    </td>
    <td>
      <span style="display: inline-block; width: 5%;">
                        <input id="chkOption3" class="chkclass" value="testing" runat="server" type="checkbox" name="chkOption3" /></span>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 5%">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 5%">
    </td>
    <td>
      <asp:Button ID="btnSendFeedback" runat="server" Width="30%" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSendFeedback_Click" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: no not working, I am still able to check all the three checkboxes. DO i need to create a `chkclass` ?

Comment: yep, you have to create class `chkclass` or change line `$('input:checkbox').not(this).attr('checked', false);`

Comment: @ELITE: not working with `$('input:checkbox').not(this).attr('checked', false);` also. @rayon: i cant see any answer.

Comment: @coder, Could you see it now ? Also defined _not working_

Comment: @Rayon: not working means, I am able to check all the three checkboxes at a time, what I want is, If i check one and go to check another the first one should get unchecked,

Comment: @Rayon: Sorry.. NO, i am not able to see first answer..! I can see only one answer and that of **ELITE**

Comment: That fiddle does not even call the js function. :/

Comment: @Rayon: not working, still able to check all the checkboxes. have a look https://i.stack.imgur.com/gG8pK.png

Comment: @coder, Do share a fiddle... Did you try running provided snippet ? Care to do so....

Comment: @Rayon I tried the fiddle. Added an alert in the function. It never called the function. Check this. https://jsfiddle.net/em103yvw/2/ 

I wonder what is going on, here.

Comment: @jitendragarg, Change load type and Never use `inline-event-binding`

Comment: @Rayon that is just for testing if it is the binding that is failing. What do you mean by load type?

Comment: @jitendragarg, In JavaScript editor section, we have a gear icon..click on that... :)

Comment: @Rayon: i created a fiddle and there it was working, but it is not working in my page :( have a look https://jsfiddle.net/0b8d5011/

Comment: yes one thing, `Uncaught ReferenceError: disablegrid is not defined`  and its code is `window.onload = function () {
            if ('<%= Request.QueryString["userid"]%>' != "") {
                disablegrid();
            }
            function disablegrid() {
                // alert('te44'); 
                document.getElementById('grid-overlay').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('grid-overlay1').style.display = 'block';
                //alert('te55'); 
            }
        };` yes fiddle is working but not the page

Comment: @coder, Ooh... Remove `function disablegrid` out of the `window.onload`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110960/discussion-between-coder-and-rayon).

Comment: @Rayon: thanks a lot for your time and patience for solving the issue.. :) Really appreciated.

Comment: @Rayon: yesterday the checkbox functionality that we did, is getting conflicted with the validation which we did long back.` $(function () {
            $("#CmdSave").click(function (e) {
                $('tr:has(:checkbox)').each(function () {
                    var len = $(this).find(':checkbox').filter(function () {
                        return this.checked;
                    }).length;
                    if (!len) {
                        alert('Atleast one checkbox from each row is mandatory');
                        e.preventDefault();  do u remember this?

Comment: @Rayon come on chat here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110960/discussion-between-coder-and-rayon wil explain you and give the fiddle too.

Comment: @Rayon: my net is very slow, i will ping u in few mins

Answer (score 0):

Do Like That..

- Uncheck other checkbox during one checkbox
- Disable other checkbox during one check

  ```
  1.
     $('input.chkclass').on('change', function () {
          $('input.chkclass').prop('checked', false);
          $(this).prop('checked', ture);
      });

  2.

      $('input.chkclass').on('change', function () {
           $('input.chkclass').prop('checked', false);
           $('input.chkclass').prop('disabled',true);
           $(this).prop('disabled',false);
           $(this)..prop('checked', true);
      });
  ```

Comment: where is the class created `chkclass` ?